# 20 hours layover in Paris. Can I get tourist visa on arrival?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, france

I am travelling from Chicago, USA to Hyderabad, India. I have a valid USA student visa on my Indian passport. I requested my booking agent for a 20-hour layover in Paris to visit the city (Been a dream for so long). Do I need a tourist visa before starting my journey or can I get one at the airport?

While coming to the USA two years ago, I had a 16-hour layover in London Heathrow and I got a 24-hour transit visa. I was able to go into the city. Can the same be possible for Paris?

Answer (score 2):

> had a 16 hours layover at London Heathrow and I got a 24 hours transit visa

No, they let you in without a visa.

> Can the same be possible for Paris?????

No, visas on arrival in Schengen countries are only issued in case of emergencies where the applicant was unable to obtain a visa in advance due to time constraints. This is hardly an emergency, hence you're not eligible.

**So you need a Schengen visa in advance**

Comment: For the archives because I know how people think: just forget about the emergency visa, it's almost never granted. The list of real emergencies is extremely short. Your emergency is not on that list.